# How to resolve `import cycle not allowed` while loading model from separate folder

Tags: go, module, model, package

I'm going to modularize my project, but I have some problems.

Normally, I will put all model files into the same package models (same folder, about 30 files), but now I want to put them into separate folders to manage them easier (each module will have their own model folder).

But if I try to put the model in separate folders like in this image, I will get "import cycle error" because they are not the same package (two tables will be used to lookup each other, this is where error happens).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Hhr.png

So is there anyway to put models in separate folders or better ways to manage models?

Comment: I know why i have this err, i want to know is there any ways to manage models in separate folders ( each module folder will have models folder which has many model files in it )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is a good strategy or not. But If I were in your situation I would try to solve it by following approach.

[image]

Let's consider we have two packages `package a` and `package b`.

```golang
package a

import ".../code/module2"

var StrA="Hi! I'm A and I'm calling B: "

func FuncA() string {
    return "Inside A"
}

func AtoB()  {
    fmt.Println(StrA+b.FuncB())
}
```

```golang
package b

import ".../code/module1"

var StrB="Hi! I'm B and I'm calling A: "

func FuncB()  string {
    return "Inside B"
}

func BtoA()  {
    fmt.Println(StrB+a.FuncA())
}
```

You cannot use function `AtoB()` or `BtoA()` because it will make a loop. One possible way you can solve it by making sub-directory inside each module. Move those part of the code that makes loop. Like here `AtoB()` and `BtoA()`.

[image]

Inside `extraA.go`:

```golang
package extended

import (
    "fmt"
    . ".../code/module1"
    b ".../code/module2"
)
func AtoB()  {
    fmt.Println(StrA+b.FuncB())
}
```

I imported `package a` using `.` so that I can use `a`'s object locally and imported `package b` to call `FuncB()`. I also move the `BtoA()` to another sub-directory inside `module2`.

Now I can use both function without making any loop.

```golang
package main

import (
    extraA ".../code/module1/extended"
    extraB ".../code/module2/extended"
)

func main()  {
    extraA.AtoB()
    extraB.BtoA()
}
```

Output:

```
Hi! I'm A and I'm calling B: Inside B
Hi! I'm B and I'm calling A: Inside A
```